# Identifying kitchen faucet stem

Tags: kitchens, faucet, plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink

I have been having a hard time identifying the stem for my kitchen sink. Any input would be appreciated. The [How to find a replacement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/68702/how-to-identify-an-old-compression-stem-in-order-to-find-a-replacement) did not help as this stem has 11 points[image: Mystery stem][image]

The broach diameter is 0.375 inches and the height is ~1.2 inches.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Can you bring the stem to a hardware store? Most have systems for identifying these, based on the stem size, points, body size, etc.

Comment: It looks like it's missing one point, so it's probably a 12, which is also the only .375" broach listed on that other page.