# Faucet cartridge identification

Tags: faucet, cartridge

I've asked around at local stores and they had no idea what it was.

A ceramic part in the valve broke so I can't just pick up a generic o-ring.

The stem has 16 teeth and <s>0.4"</s> 0.365" diameter.
The valve is 5 inches long.

[image]

[image]

Comment: excellent photos! sorry i can't help.

Comment: Does the lack of a brand mark mean this fixture would have been made in the Far East? Do all of the domestically manufactured faucets have a brand mark? Or have there always been domestically manufactured faucets that were without a brand mark?

Comment: @JimStewart, if anything had a brand, it would be the spout.  In the US, handles typically don't have marks and neither do the cartridges.  That said, there are a few big brands that are popular.  Cheap no-brand stuff is more common now that people can order stuff online, but not very common even in the recent past.

Comment: I tried to find it on this site, but couldn't.  Count the number of splines on the top where the handle attaches and see if you can have better luck: https://www.faucetpartsplus.com/

Comment: Based on spline count/size stuff points to sterling which seemed wrong. I have no idea what the norm is for domestic faucets are (in the US), I've been lucky enough to not have to do much plumbing.

I pasted an answer, I actually read the text on the aerator before and thought it said "hardened" (and found it quite strange it would say that on brass). Couldn't find any markings on the bath itself though.

Comment: [How to identify an old compression stem in order to find a replacement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/68705/23295) @JPhi1618 - It's a lot easier to read my transcript of that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a brand on the sinks that are the same style. The company that made the faucet appears to be Harden. The style of the cartridge has similarities to others I'm seeing online for Harden.

The part appears to be "harden 185"

[image]

Comment: If it's a Harden, it's a .370" broach. If it's actually .40", it's a Sterling. [How to identify an old compression stem in order to find a replacement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/68702/how-to-identify-an-old-compression-stem-in-order-to-find-a-replacement)

Comment: You would appear to be correct. That's my bad for being too lazy to get a better measuring tool.

Comment: NP. Excellent work. Keep 'em coming, and check out some of our other sites.